# how to return a value from eventlistner function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onload = function() {
  var count = 0;
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change',
    handleFileSelect, false);
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    console.log("hariii");
    var files = evt.target.files;
    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      count++;
      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img style="height: 75px; border: 1px solid #000; 
            margin: 5 px " src="
            ',
            e.target.result,
            '" title="', escape(theFile.name),
            '"/>'
          ].join('');  document.getElementById('thumbnail').insertBefore(span null);
        };
      })(f);
      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
    //console.log(count);
    return (count)
  }
}
```

Im not good in javascript. I want to return a value 'count' from eventlistnernfunction I tried with this

```
var x = handleFileSelect(evt);
console.log(x);
```

but it give error. 'handlefileselect is not defined'. I know this is a silly but i'm new to javascript. appreciate your ideas and helps.

Comment: try defining handleFileSelect at the top of the window.onload function

Comment: @AyushGupta Function declarations are hoisted so that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: for a start `handlefileselect` is not the same as `handleFileSelect`

Comment: @CarlEdwards ah, wasnt sure that was the case with client side JS

Comment: @AyushGupta Fundamentally it's always the case.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your span.innerHTML

Comment: @AyushGupta it also give the same error

Comment: note: returning a value in an event handler makes little sense - where is this value going to be returned to?

Comment: Make sure the function is assigned before it's being called https://jsfiddle.net/c198wLyn/14/

Comment: @DanielTate no syntax error. otherthings are work fine. return value is the case

Comment: @JaromandaX  i'll try to pass it in to another function. first i try to return it in to out of the function

Comment: returning it is pointless as I've already said, so why even "try" something pointless?

Comment: Are you calling `console.log(handleFileSelect(evt))` outside `window.onload`?

Comment: Event Handling functions are Asynchronous.

Comment: If objective is to get `count`, then you needn't have a return, `count` is a global and it's as easy as getting document or window.

Comment: @vibhor1997a it also not working same issue

Comment: @zer00ne if you can give me a demo i'll appreciate

Comment: @ThilankaUmayangaJayarathna ok see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to access return values. but it's not standard way. it's a small trick. make hidden field in html body part and assign javascript variable value to that hidden field. when that value want, get that field value by document.ElementBy method. It work fine but not a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about why the variable `count` isn't working as a return in this event listener (or any other event listener/handler/callback), is not because it's an event (fill in the blank), it's because `count`'s nature and purpose. It's assumed purpose is that `count` is a simple counter, and a counter is usually a global (which it is in this case), and incremented within an iteration (which it is as well in this case). As a global, `count` is accessible from anywhere.  You can get the value of `count` at any point after it's been incremented (`count++`).

This demo is a modified ***working*** demo of the one found in [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). If you want details, go there:

### Demo

```js
var files = document.getElementById('files');
var count = 0;

files.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var counter = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
  var dock = document.getElementById('thumbnail');
  var files = evt.target.files;

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var f = files[i];
    count++;
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(file) {
      return function(e) {
        var str = `
          <span class='frm'>
          <img src="${e.target.result}" class='tmb' title="${escape(file.name)}">
          </span>`;
        dock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
      };
    })(f);
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
  counter.textContent = count;
  console.log(count);
}
```

```css
.tmb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px
}

.frm {
  display: inline-block;
}

label, input {
  font: 700 16px/1.45 Consolas;
  color: red;
}

label {font-size:32px}
```

```html
<input id='files' type='file' name='files' accept="image/*"> <label for='files'></label><br>
<output id='thumbnail'></output>
```